# Google Sheets - Stacked Area Chart

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a chart in Google Sheets and having difficulty.

Here is 3 simple columns:

```
created     department  person
01/11/2020  finance     a
01/11/2020  finance     b
02/11/2020  finance     c
01/11/2020  hr          d
04/11/2020  hr          e
01/11/2020  misc        f
03/11/2020  misc        g
02/11/2020  misc        h
04/11/2020  misc        i
```

I want to create a stacked area chart which has:
X-Axis - date
Y-Axis - count of person
stacked colours - new colour for each department

Hope this makes sense?
I can't seem to get anywhere with Google Sheets. When I try to enter department or person as the series it tells me it is an invalid data type.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pivot tables are my friend!

Row: created

Column: department

values: COUNTA(person)

[image]